# Сравнение значений поля ввода в каждом блоке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Есть форма с несколькими блоками в которых, в свою очередь присутствуют по два инпута `from` и `to`. Есть скрипт, который сверяет введенные в них значения и выбивает ошибку, если значение первого инпута превышает значение второго (и наоборот). Но он работает только для одного блока, сделать его таким образом, чтобы он работал во всех подобных блоках формы у меня не выходит. Ниже два сниппета - первый со скриптом, который работает на одном блоке и второй - мой вариант скрипта для всех блоков, но он не работает. [Ссылка на песочницу](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/JEbKQv).

Сниппет первый:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#price-range-from").on("change", function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($("#price-range-to").val())) {
      $('.filter-item .error').addClass('visible').text("First value can't be larger then second");
      $(this).addClass('error-field').val('');
    }
    else {
      $('.filter-item .error').removeClass('visible');
      $(this).removeClass('error-field');
    }
  });
  $("#price-range-to").on("change", function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt($("#price-range-from").val())) {
      $('.filter-item .error').addClass('visible').text("Second value can't be smaller then first");
      $(this).addClass('error-field').val('');
    }
    else {
      $('.filter-item .error').removeClass('visible');
      $(this).removeClass('error-field');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.from-to-form label {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.from-to-form label:last-of-type {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"] {
    width: 83px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;

    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s;
    -ms-transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]:hover {
    border: 2px solid #ffe69a;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid #ffe69a;
    background-color: #fef5d3;
    outline: none;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.from-to-form input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}


.filter-item .error {
    display: none;
    color: #d66464;
}
.filter-item .error.visible {
    display: block;
}
.filter-item .filter-body .error-field {
    border-color: #d66464;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price-range" class="filter-item half-width right">
  <div class="filter-item-header">
    <h3 class="filter-title">Price range of in-app purchases <span>($)</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-body">
    <div class="from-to-form">
      <label for="price-range-from">From</label>
      <input id="price-range-from" class="from" type="number" placeholder="15">

      <label for="price-range-to">To</label>
      <input id="price-range-to" class="to" type="number" placeholder="232">

      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="number-of-downloads" class="filter-item half-width left">
  <div class="filter-item-header">
    <h3 class="filter-title">Number of downloads</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-body">
    <div class="from-to-form">
      <label for="downloads-from">From</label>
      <input id="downloads-from" class="from" type="number" placeholder="0">

      <label for="downloads-to">To</label>
      <input id="downloads-to" class="to" type="number" placeholder="45454335">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сниппет второй:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filter-item .from').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', function () {
      if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).closest('.to').val())) {
        $(this).closest('.filter-item .error').addClass('visible').text("First value can't be larger then second");
        $(this).addClass('error-field').val('');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.filter-item .error').removeClass('visible');
        $(this).removeClass('error-field');
      }
    })
  })

  $('.filter-item .to').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', function () {
      if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).closest('.from').val())) {
        $(this).closest('.filter-item .error').addClass('visible').text("First value can't be larger then second")
        $(this).addClass('error-field').val('');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.filter-item .error').removeClass('visible');
        $(this).removeClass('error-field');
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.from-to-form label {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.from-to-form label:last-of-type {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"] {
    width: 83px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;

    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s;
    -ms-transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]:hover {
    border: 2px solid #ffe69a;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid #ffe69a;
    background-color: #fef5d3;
    outline: none;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.from-to-form input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}


.filter-item .error {
    display: none;
    color: #d66464;
}
.filter-item .error.visible {
    display: block;
}
.filter-item .filter-body .error-field {
    border-color: #d66464;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price-range" class="filter-item half-width right">
  <div class="filter-item-header">
    <h3 class="filter-title">Price range of in-app purchases <span>($)</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-body">
    <div class="from-to-form">
      <label for="price-range-from">From</label>
      <input id="price-range-from" class="from" type="number" placeholder="15">

      <label for="price-range-to">To</label>
      <input id="price-range-to" class="to" type="number" placeholder="232">

      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="number-of-downloads" class="filter-item half-width left">
  <div class="filter-item-header">
    <h3 class="filter-title">Number of downloads</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-body">
    <div class="from-to-form">
      <label for="downloads-from">From</label>
      <input id="downloads-from" class="from" type="number" placeholder="0">

      <label for="downloads-to">To</label>
      <input id="downloads-to" class="to" type="number" placeholder="45454335">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы делаете не так то, что используете повторяющиеся значения атрибута `id`, которые должны быть уникальны в пределах страницы. Используйте выборку по `class`-у.

Comment: Не вижу повторения айдишников...

Comment: @Igor, вы наверное посмотрели на первый сниппет. Тот скрипт работает на один блок, во втором варианте я как-раз таки пытался воспользоваться классами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задаёте функцию только для одной формы с полями. Вам нужно задать общую функцию сравнения и применить ко всем полям по id или как я в своём варианте сделал - по классу:

```js
function comparison(e, first, second) {
  if (parseInt(second) > parseInt(first)) {
    $(e).parents('.filter-item').find('.error').addClass('visible').text("First value can't be larger then second");
    $(e).addClass('error-field').val('');
  } else {
    $(e).parents('.filter-item').find('.error').removeClass('visible');
    $(e).removeClass('error-field');
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".from").on("change", function() {
    comparison(this, $(this).parents('.filter-item').find(".to").val(), $(this).val());
  });
  $(".to").on("change", function() {
    comparison(this, $(this).val(), $(this).parents('.filter-item').find(".from").val())
  });
});
```

```css
.from-to-form label {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.from-to-form label:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"] {
  width: 83px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s;
  -ms-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]:hover {
  border: 2px solid #ffe69a;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid #ffe69a;
  background-color: #fef5d3;
  outline: none;
}
.from-to-form input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.from-to-form input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
.filter-item .error {
  display: none;
  color: #d66464;
}
.filter-item .error.visible {
  display: block;
}
.filter-item .filter-body .error-field {
  border-color: #d66464;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price-range" class="filter-item half-width right">
  <div class="filter-item-header">
    <h3 class="filter-title">Price range of in-app purchases <span>($)</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-body">
    <div class="from-to-form">
      <label for="price-range-from">From</label>
      <input id="price-range-from" class="from" type="number" placeholder="15">

      <label for="price-range-to">To</label>
      <input id="price-range-to" class="to" type="number" placeholder="232">

      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="number-of-downloads" class="filter-item half-width left">
  <div class="filter-item-header">
    <h3 class="filter-title">Number of downloads</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-body">
    <div class="from-to-form">
      <label for="downloads-from">From</label>
      <input id="downloads-from" class="from" type="number" placeholder="0">

      <label for="downloads-to">To</label>
      <input id="downloads-to" class="to" type="number" placeholder="45454335">
      
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`first` в функции всегда должно быть меньше `second`. По этому указываете в функции сначала `this`, потом поле, которое должно быть меньше и потом уже поле, которое должно быть больше.